# How to print output vector from capsule layer?

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, vector, keras

I am working with capsule networks. My reference paper is [here](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1710.09829.pdf). The paper states that the primary capsule layer generates 8D vector of pose parameter. 
My question is can we get the vector from layer's output and print that 8D vector?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the question is tagged with keras, I assume the model is built using keras library.

> can we get the vector from layer's output and print that 8D vector?

Yes you can. First you have to access the inputs of the model and  the output of the capsule layer.

```
inputs = model.input
outputs = model.layers[index_of_the_caps_layer].output
```

Keras provides keras.backend.function to run computation graph. You need to pass numpy array for model input placeholder

```
import keras.backend as K 
input_values # Input values to the model 
function = K.function([inputs, K.learning_phase()], outputs )
caps_output = function([input_values, 1.0])
print(caps_output)
```

Comment: What is input_values here? The image whose 8D vector we want to print?

Comment: Yes, the image you want to analyze. E.g if you have trained the model on mnist dataset the input_values is an array with shape  (BATCH_SIZE, 28, 28, 1). I.e the input_values variables should have a shape that the model expects.

Comment: I do the same for mnist image but I am not getting any output. Is there any need to print anything?

Comment: Try printing the `caps_output`.

Comment: Will it output multidimensional array? Asking this to know whether I am going right or not.

Comment: If what you are trying is an implementation of "Dynamic Routing Between Capsules" paper, the output of the primary caps has a shape of (Number_of_capsules, Capsule_dimension) => (N, 8). So yes the output is multidimensional(2D) array.